# How find the row containing the maximum value and its associated year, when the Year Column contains multiple years in R

Tags: r, select, time-series, max

How find the row containing the maximum value and its associated year, when the Year Column contains multiple years. My data frame contains monthly river discharge data from january2013 till December 2020. for example if I wanted to find the row containing maximum discharge for the year 2013 or I would like to find out both maximum discharge for 2013 and the date (date/month/year) associated with that particular maximum discharge. How would I do that? in R?

| Year | Discharge |
| --- | --- |
| 1/1/2013 | 23 |
| 2/1/2013 | 45 |
| - - | -- |
| 12/31/2020 | 80 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can convert the column to Date class, get the `year` as a separate column, do a group by and `slice` the `max` row

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df1 %>%
    group_by(year = year(mdy(Year))) %>%
    slice_max(n = 1, order_by = Discharge) %>%
    ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  Year       Discharge  year
  <chr>          <int> <dbl>
1 2/1/2013          45  2013
2 12/31/2020        80  2020
```

---

if there are multiple formats in the 'Year' column, use `parse_date` from `parsedate`

```
library(parsedate)
df1 %>%
    group_by(year = year(parse_date(Year))) %>%
    slice_max(n = 1, order_by = Discharge) %>%
    ungroup
```

#### Update

Based on the `dput` in the comments, the 'Date' column is already in `Date` class

```
df1 %>%
   group_by(year= year(Date)) %>%
   slice_max(n = 1, order_by = Discharge, with_ties = FALSE) %>%
    ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  Date       Discharge  year
  <date>         <dbl> <dbl>
1 2018-06-07    0.0116  2018
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Year = c("1/1/2013", "2/1/2013", "12/31/2020"), 
    Discharge = c(23L, 45L, 80L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Thank you! I am not sure what it is calculating and also getting a Warning message as below :
Problem with `mutate()` column `year`.
i `year = year(mdy(Year))`.
i All formats failed to parse. No formats found.

Comment: @SankarManalilkadaSasidharan your input showed the date format in month/day/year format.  Do you have any other formats

Comment: @SankarManalilkadaSasidharan try the updated code with `parse_date`

Comment: Thank you but it still giving me error. What I would like to find is just the row containing maximum discharge value and its associated date. My Year column (eg format 2013-01-01, 2013-01-02, 2013-01-03......till 2020-12-31) contains contains several years.

Comment: @SankarManalilkadaSasidharan please show a small reproducible example that shows the error.  Your input shows only the year column in a single format i.e. monthh day year.  If you have some values as `hello` or `"2009"` only then it is not a date format and it will result in  warning with NA values

Comment: Thank you. It is working now, unfortunately selecting only the start date. Not the row containing the maximum value of the discharge and its associated year!

Comment: @SankarManalilkadaSasidharan Your question title is `How find the row containing the maximum value and its associated year`  How is the `maximm` value changed to `miinimum` now

Comment: @ akrun sorry typo :)!

Comment: @SankarManalilkadaSasidharan the `slice_max` will select only the row containing the max value in Discharge and when you specify `n=1`, it returns a single row for that group (unless there are ties)

Comment: Thank you! both codes are working but both are selecting the wrong values.  It not selecting the max values.

Comment: @SankarManalilkadaSasidharan is it possible that your `Discharge` column is not numeic class.  Can you check `class(df1$Discharge)`

Comment: @SankarManalilkadaSasidharan a better approach would be to update your post with `dput` so that I can get the exact structure of your data.  i.e. take few rows of data and dput i.e. `dput(droplevels(head(df1, 20)))` then, we don't need to clarify it on comments

Comment: it is numeric  ; > class(df1$Discharge)
[1] "numeric"

Comment: @SankarManalilkadaSasidharan sorry, there was a typo.  Can you remove the quotes around "Discharge" and run it

Comment: structure(list(Date = structure(c(17689, 17689, 17689, 17689, 
17689, 17689, 17689, 17689, 17689, 17689, 17689, 17689, 17689, 
17689, 17689, 17689, 17689, 17689, 17689, 17689), class = "Date"), 
    Discharge = c(0.011609888, 0.011609888, 0.011609888, 
    0.011609888, 0.010477216, 0.010477216, 0.010477216, 0.010477216, 
    0.010477216, 0.010477216, 0.010477216, 0.010477216, 0.00934, 
    0.00934, 0.00934, 0.00934, 0.00934, 0.00934, 0.00934, 0.0085
    )), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: @SankarManalilkadaSasidharan it should work now.  Please run it again with the updated code

Comment: > class(df1$Date)
[1] "Date"

Comment: @SankarManalilkadaSasidharan in the dput, your dates are in the correct format i.e. year-month-day instead of `month/day/year`

Comment: Probably yu have changed the `date` class.  When you show input with a different format, it is kind of misleading

Comment: ..it is working now! but it is only selecting maximum value for an year. Not for every year! (example: it is selecting the max value for only 2018, and not for 2019,2020).

Comment: @SankarManalilkadaSasidharan Please check my updated code.  Your column name is different i.e. it is `Date` and it is already in `Date` class.  We are grouping by 'Year'

Comment: @ akrun Thank you so much for helping out. the code is working but there was a typo. I have removed the %>%  in front of slice_max. Thank you so much           `df1 %>%
   group_by(year= year(Date)) %>%
    slice_max(n = 1, order_by = Discharge, with_ties = FALSE) %>%
    ungroup`                                and I have  accepted your solution! Thank you once again